# Automated model selection functions in statistics

Tags: regression, time-series, automatic-algorithms

I am aware of auto.arima() in R for the automatic selection of a seasonal ARIMA (time series) model in R and functions such as leaps() in R that do automatic best subset feature selection in linear regression. Other functions, such as cv.glmnet(), for ridge or lasso regression for high dimensional datasets, are basically automatic too.

This may be too broad a question, but does anyone know of a list of other functions (not necessarily in R) that allow for the automatic selection of models in different areas of statistics?

Disclaimer: As a warning to future readers that seek the answer to this question, obviously there are potential pitfalls in automated model selection functions. There are certain steps that such functions do not do and one must be wary of the assumptions that are made by such functions.

Comment: http://www.automaticstatistician.com may be relevant here.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'll check it out! I'm reading through your book Forecasting: Principles and Practice at the moment. Did you write other 'automated' functions like auto.arima()?

Comment: ets() and tbats() are also automated forecasting functions.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll be learning about them in due course while I go through fpp3.